# Can I display a webpart as output of another webpart?

Tags: web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, react

Can I output a webpart as part of another webpart rather than duplicating the HTML?

For example, if I have a 'Person' webpart that outputs a contact card, can I have a 'People' webpart that outputs a list of 'Person' webparts?

I know I can import that 'Person' react component, but I'd like to be able to just output the webpart, for example, if one of the webparts is a third party which I don't have the source for.